# Как изменить значение в базе данных по id с помощью Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

К примеру я взял данные c базы данных по id:

```
var game = db.Games.Find(id);
```

что-то с ними делаю, изменяю и мне нужно снова отправить, на туже строку где равно = id, т.е. заменить.

```
    public class GameContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Это DbSet , с помощью контекста подключаюсь

Comment: `game.Caption = "new value"; db.SaveChanges();` ?

Comment: Да, спасибо, новичок просто

Comment: game.Caption = "new value"; только обновить забыли: db.Games.Update(game);  db.SaveChanges();